Comparing .NET RSA and ECDSA signature algorithms
In System.Security.Cryptography, the RSA and ECDsa classes both implement SignData and SignHash methods.
Aligning with cryptographic standards, the SignData methods require a HashAlgorithmName, since the input data is hashed and then passed to SignHash to be signed, rather that signing the data directly.
Examples from ECDsa:
byte[] SignData(byte[] data, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, DSASignatureFormat signatureFormat);
byte[] SignHash(byte[] hash, DSASignatureFormat signatureFormat);

Examples from RSA:
byte[] SignData(byte[] data, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding);
byte[] SignHash(byte[] hash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding);

The ECDsa methods make sense since SignData accepts a byte[], HashAlgorithmName, and DSASignatureFormat, therefore hashing the data, and passing the resulting hash to SignHash, which accepts a byte[] and DSASignatureFormat.
RSA on the other hand requires HashAlgorithmName for both SignData and SignHash, even though internally it follows the same process of hashing the data first, and then signing over the hash.
My question is, why does SignHash require an argument of type HashAlgorithmName?

For RSA, not only the hash but also the Digest OID is included in the signature (as DER encoding of the DigestInfo value, see EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5). Therefore, the hash alone is not sufficient for an RFC8017-compliant signature with RSA.

For the second RSA padding variant (RSASSA-PSS), the digest must be specified, as it is hashed more than once, so that the hash of the message alone is not sufficient, see EMSA-PSS.

I do not think there is any real reason except Microsoft is using the string as part of creating the hash.  The longer the hash input the harder to break.  A hash is not unique since two different inputs can create the same hash (usually very small probability).  If a hacker does not know the name it will take longer to break.

The real question is why the configuration doesn't accept a configuration class like it does in Java, making the API much more flexible. I don't think cryptographic agility is always feasible or even all that useful at this low level of functionality (scheme rather than protocol level), but in this case it should be easy to support it.

For the sake of completeness, however, it should also be mentioned that the .NET implementation essentially adheres to the defaults and recommendations of RFC8017. This covers (presumably) the majority of use cases. And if a configuration deviating from the defaults or recommendations is really necessary (e.g. if PSS and MGF1 digests differ), the functionality can be supplemented by a third-party libraray (such as BC).
